# How to Clear notifications once and not be bothered/repeated again?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications

Simple yet annoying behaviour of Android (Galaxy S3)

Notifications appear for many apps (email, games, messages etc.,) but once I view them (by a slide down, not by opening/responding to each of them ) I want them to be gone. They keep on repeating & appearing again and again until I respond to the notification.

ie., If it is a new email, I'm being notified repeatedly until I open the Email program!  I find this extremely annoying. I don't want to Turn off Notification because they are useful. But, I don't want to be bugged by them as well. 
Good, show me once & then disappear.

How do I get this behaviour (View once, clear notifications & the same notifications don't repeat?

Comment: Interesting. This isn't normal Android behavior. I wonder if it's a midification Samsung made.

Comment: Having same issue on lg g2x